# The vector has a size = 2, but it still has a value in the index 100

Tags: c++, c++11

I run the following codes in http://cpp.sh/.
The outputs show that name1.size()=2, but name1[100]=10;

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> name;
    vector <int> name1;
    name1.push_back(1);
    name1.push_back(3);
    vector <int> name2;
    name2.push_back(4);
    name.push_back(name1);
    name.push_back(name2);
    name1[100]=10;
    cout<<name1.size()<<endl;
    cout<<name1[100];
}
```

Comment: That's undefined behaviour == wrong. Anything can happen. Some value, crashing, strange behaviour of all sorts, ...

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Fix the obvious bug in your code and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you are invoking undefined behavior, so you won't find any further specification of what must happen in the standard.

The long answer is that C++ is an unsafe language and doesn't guarantee any type of deterministic error for various invalid operations, including accessing a `vector` out of bounds using `operator[]`. Instead, it uses the broad brush of *undefined behavior* which basically allows *anything* at all to happen: the idea being that by allowing the user the flexibility to avoid checks which they know are redundant, good performance can be achieved for well-behaved code.

If you want the vector to check that you aren't accessing an out-of-bounds index, no problem - just use the [`vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) which does exactly that, and throws `std::out_of_range` for invalid accesses.

As for why your particular code is (apparently) returning a value, note that a typical<sup>1</sup> implementation of `operator[]` will just access the underlying storage directly, meaning that at the assembly level you will access whatever is `100 * sizeof(int)` bytes from the start of the storage underlying the vector. That's usually going to be something random on the heap (since the storage is usually allocated on the heap), but it may also be an inaccessible address, resulting in an access violation.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some compilers such as MSVC will provide more error checking in "debug" modes, which might cause `operator[]` to call `vector.at()` instead, which *does* do range checking and has defined behavior, and at least a few other compilers/standard libraries seem to be jumping on board with that idea.

Comment: Visual Studio has a long tradition of checking for correct usage on all STL containers in Debug compilation mode. This includes checking for index out of bounds on std::vector::operator[].

Comment: Thanks for the note, @Sjoerd, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87df7569e5d99715).

**You declared:**

```
vector <int> name1; // An empty vector. name1.size = 0 here.
```

**Once you push_back the two values.**

```
name1.push_back(1);
name1.push_back(3); // name1.size = 2, Index starts at 0, so
                    // name[0] = 1 and name[1] = 2
```

**So the value for:**

```
name1[100] = undefined (garbage). // You never initialised this value, so it yields unexpected behaviour.
```

An alternative for this is to use a default initialiser for an int vector and declare it like this:

```
vector <int> name1(101);
```

Here:

```
name1[100] = 0 // Because you defined it in the vector constructor to initialise 100 default values.
name1[0] = 0 // This is the first value of the now initialised vector.
name1[69] = 0 // This is the 70th value of the initialised vector.
name[101] = undefined // Again, this is undefined (garbage). You defined a vector of size n = 101, so that means the vector's range is [0,100]. 0 index counts and the last value is n - 1 (101 - 1 = 100). Index 101 is undefined.
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative. I think it would be better to stress that the storage was never *allocated* rather than confusing the issue with initialisation - though you're not wrong.

Comment: `name1` only has a size of `2`, so there is no such value as `name1[100]`.  Using an index out of bounds just causes undefined behaviour.  (Your answer suggests there is an uninitialized value or something).

Comment: It is out of bounds, yes, but it compiles and executes yielding a result unlike a normal array because operator[] is used instead of .at(). I never even implied that there was a stored value there. You're being overly fuzzy over words. Out of bounds and not allocated can be related, they're not mutually exclusive. My wording could be better, like@BrettHale suggested, surely, as could anyone's. Essentially, for interpreting my words wrongly, which some people did interpret right you down voted me. A bit subjective in my opinion, but you do what you have to do. I'd suggest an edit alternately.